# PyQt Table Widget delete selected row from table and Database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyqt

[image]

[image]

I need help on this lines of code.I want to select a row and delete the row from the table as well from database.

```
def deleteProduct(self):

    row = self.products_table.currentRow()

    if row > -1:
        currentproductid = (self.products_table.item(row, 0).text(), )
        query = session.query(Product).filter(Product.product_id==currentproductid).first()
        session.delete(query)
        session.commit()

        self.mainTable.removeRow(currentRow)
```

I am getting this error:

```
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: <exception str() failed>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def deleteProduct(self):
        row = self.products_table.currentRow()

        currentproductid = (self.products_table.item(row, 0).text() )
        product_name = (self.products_table.item(row, 1).text() )
        query = session.query(Product).filter(Product.product_id==str(currentproductid)).first()
        session.delete(query)
        session.commit()
        self.products_table.removeRow(row)
```